# An inequality property of the Fibonacci sequence

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations

Given the Fibonacci sequence $F_n$, Wikipedia says (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#List_of_Fibonacci_numbers) $$ F_{2n-1} = F_n^2+F^2 _{n-1}$$ so that $$F_{2n-1}>F^2_n$$

What is the smallest such k for which $$F_{n+k}>F^2_n\,\,?$$

I'm not sure where to start or to find smaller values than $2n-1$

Comment: You could try coming up with the general expression for the recurrence relation via mathematical induction if you want. It is the most straightforward way I can think of doing such a problem.

Comment: A fixed smallest j likely doesn't exist for all starting values. Suppose it does, the if you multiply the starting values by $K$, we get that $Kn_{i+j}\geq K^2 n_i ^2 $, which is clearly false for large enough $K$. So you will need to provide more context.

Comment: Also, a fixed $j$ doesn't exist for all values of $n$. Note that in your Fibonacci number, your value of $j$ is equal to $n$. So, if you're willing for that to happen, it's best to denote it as $j_n$. If so, $j_n = n \pm 1$ is a good approximation, but as mentioned above, dependent on your starting values. Check the original question again.

Comment: I've edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$k=n-1$ is the minimum possible value.

We have $F_{2n-1}=F_n^2+F_{n-1}^2$.  Rewrite the LHS as $F_{2n-2}+F_{2n-3}$, so $$F_{2n-2}=F_n^2+F_{n-1}^2-F_{2n-3}$$
But now $F_{2n-3}=F_{n-1}^2+F_{n-2}^2$.  Substituting, we get $$F_{2n-2}=F_n^2-F_{n-2}^2<F_n^2$$
Hence even the term immediately preceding $F_{2n-1}$ is less than $F_n^2$.